# Boolean memory efficient linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++17

How would you implement a memory efficient linked list of booleans? Obviously the next node pointer is much larger than the payload itself in the conventional linked list.

Comment: What operations do you need to support?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve at all?

Comment: I do not need it for anything. I am just curious, but I think push_back() pop_back() push_front() pop_front() erase() swap() insert() size() empty() would all be necessary for a robust linked list.

Comment: i think std::list<bool> ?

Comment: @jonas_toth I am not interested in STL, unless we are talking about the way they implemented a specialized template for bool

Comment: A bool is 1 bit. If you wanted to make a single linked list then you would need a pointer for every bit and a pointer, depending on the machine, is either 32 bits or 64 so for every bool bit you will be using 33/63 bits of memory. Personally, I do not think there is a way to make it memory efficient as the overhead for the data structure is just to large for a bool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Align nodes on something more than 1-byte boundaries, and use the least significant bit of the 'next' pointer to encode the bool value.

I'm not very good at coding directly into text boxes, but something along the lines of this:

```
struct node {
    static_assert(alignof(node) > 1, "node is insufficiently aligned");

    bool get_value() const {
        return static_cast<bool>(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(next) & 0x1);
    }

    void set_value(bool value) {
        size_t ptr = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(next);
        ptr &= ~1;
        ptr |= static_cast<size_t>(value);
        next = reinterpret_cast<node*>(ptr);
    }

    node* get_next() const {
        size_t ptr = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(next);
        ptr &= ~1;
        return reinterpret_cast<node*>(ptr);
    }

    void set_next(node* n) {
        bool value = get_value();
        next = n;
        set_value(value);
    }

private:
    node* next;
};
```

Comment: Could you further explain the process of using the least significant bit for encoding. Correct me if I am wrong, but the address stored in the next pointer is to be determined by the memory address of the next node. Wouldn't changing it make it point to a different location in memory?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a rough sketch of what the code would look like.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rough idea. In your linked list node, have two fields, first is a pointer to the next node, the second is another integer member of equal size to a pointer on your system. For example, on a 64-bit architecture:

```
struct node {
  node *next;
  uint64_t bits;
}
```

Each node then stores 64 booleans instead of just the one in a standard linked list implementation. Many operations become less time efficient (but that's the usual trade-off for memory/space efficiency) as you will have to do some bit shifting and something akin to tree balancing when you add a 65th boolean or insert into a "full" bitset, etc. (Also, thinking about this further, you probably need a 3rd member telling you the number of bits used.)

However, there are some advantages to this as a simple structure like this fits into a cache very well.

Like I said, this is a just a rough idea and there are probably a ton of pitfalls in implementing something like this. Write good tests.

Comment: How is this more memory efficient than just using 1 bit for the bool? Since  now he would be using 124 bits per node instead of 63?

Comment: @GaryJohnson that's 128 bits (well, you would need that extra member with the number of used bits I think? so add some more, or maybe steal some bits from `bits`) for up to 64 bools though, so space usage may be as low as 2 bits/item

Comment: You would need at least 128 + 8 (one byte), giving 2.125 bits per boolean.

Comment: @harold: The usual bit-buffer trick is set a single most (or least) significant bit indication indicating the length. Hence one bit of overhead for the length.

Comment: @doynax wait how does that work? There aren't just two cases here, so it seems like it should require more than 1 bit

Comment: Now that I think about it, removing a bit from the middle of such a linked list would be problematic and potentially really heavy, especially if order is important. I guess each node would need its own count for number of bits used. Then, you would just rearrange one or two nodes when removing or adding an entry.

Comment: @harold: The trick is that there are effectively unused bits in the shorter cases. The scheme is that the length is the position of the highest set bit, and everything below it is the actual payload. So for a 4-bit field you'd get 0001 for zero, 001x for one, 01xx for two and 1xxx for three bits of payload. Well, you get the idea.

Comment: So the first 4-bits provides information about length of bools that are being stored in `bits`.  Does this imply that all of the bits per a node (stored in `bits`) would have to be contiguous?

Comment: @Brandon: No, that was merely example using 4-bit integers where the X-bits store the data. The highest 1-bit marks the start of the data field which is stored below it. So in a 64-bit integer you'd squeeze in 0-63 bits of data plus the sentinel bit on top. But, yes, the data would be contiguous.